# Average value and confidence interval with different precisions of a measurement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, statistics

Imagine you have to measure thickness of a paper sheet using only a caliper which provides a precision to $\Theta $ mm. You start with a stack of 10 sheets and the caliper reads ${{l}_{1}}$  mm. Then you try measuring of a stack of 20, 30, 40 and 50 sheets and obtain lengths of ${{l}_{2}}$, ${{l}_{3}}$, ${{l}_{4}}$ and ${{l}_{5}}$. Naturally, the actual thickness of a sheet can be written as $${{l}_{pn}}=\frac{{{l}_{n}}}{n}\pm \frac{\Theta }{n}$$ where $n=10,20,30,40,50$. It we were to assume that all the sheets have identical thickness, then the most precise will be the measurement with the stack of 50 pages $${{l}_{p50}}=\frac{{{l}_{50}}}{50}\pm \frac{\Theta }{50}$$ My question is how to calculate the actual thickness of one sheet using the data provided. I’m not entirely sure how to calculate the confidence interval of lets’s say $95$ percent.

Edit: Ok, I’l try to reformulate my question. Given $n$ measurements (${{x}_{1}},{{x}_{2}},...,{{x}_{n}}$) with a fixed precision (systematic error) of $\Delta {{X}_{syst}}$, the average result be expressed as $$\bar{x}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{x}_{i}}}}{n}$$ we can also easily calculate the statistical error $\Delta {{X}_{stat}}$. Obviously, the total error for this measurement$$\Delta {{X}_{total}}=\sqrt{{{\left( \Delta {{X}_{syst}} \right)}^{2}}+{{\left( \Delta {{X}_{stat}} \right)}^{2}}}$$ My question was, how to calculate $\Delta {{X}_{total}}$ if $\Delta {{X}_{syst}}$ changes in every measurement?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You appear to have answered your own question : "the most precise will be the measurement with the stack of 50 pages". BTW the formula should use $\pm\Theta/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question as follows: We have the measurements $\{x_{10},x_{20},x_{30},x_{40},x_{50}\}$ of $n=10, 20, 30, 40, 50$ sheets of papers and we like to obtain an average thickness of a single sheet and its  standard deviation. The first part is straight forward:

1. The **average** thickness of a single sheet of paper is given by
   $$
   \bar x_1 = \frac{\sum_{n} x_n}{\sum_n n} = \frac{x_{10}+x_{20}+x_{30}+x_{40}+x_{50}}{10+20+30+40+50} 
   $$
   which is the same as if we would have 150 measurements of a single sheet.
2. In order to estimate the **standard deviation**, we have to calculate "deviations from the average value". There are different ways to make use of the obtained information. E.g. one could calculate five deviations  $\Delta_n = x_{n}-n\bar x_1$, and then use a "weighted average" to obtain an estimate of $\sigma_1$. However, a much simpler method is to scale the measurements using
   $$
   \{x^{(j)}_{10} \}
   = \{\frac{x_{n}}{n/10}\}
   = \{\frac{x_{10}}{1}, \frac{x_{20}}{2}, \frac{x_{30}}{3}, \frac{x_{40}}{4}, \frac{x_{50}}{5}\}
   $$
   Like this we obtain five datapoints for $n=10$ sheets of paper. Now we can apply the standard formula for the standard deviation of a sample,
   $s_{10} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{5-1}\sum_{j=1}^5 (x^{(j)}_{10} - \bar x_{10})^2}$ -- note that I use $\bar x_{10} = 10 \cdot \bar x_{1}$. Finally, we use the central limit theorem, $\sigma_n = \sigma_1/\sqrt{n}$, to estimate  $\sigma_1$. This last step is questionable. Thus, check out when the central limit theorem is applicable.